# How to resolve "added by us" git cherry-pick conflict?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick, git-merge-conflict

I ran into a problem with git, during a conflict resolution after a cherry-pick. Problem involved modification made on file that was `git mv` in a previous commit.

Here is an example of the full command to reproduce:

```
mkdir git_repository && cd git_repository
git init
echo "foo" > myFooFile
git add myFooFile 
git commit -m "First commit add myFooFile"

git checkout -b branch-a
rm myFooFile
echo "bar" > myBarFile
git add -A
git commit -m "rm myFooFile add myBarFile"

git checkout master
git mv myFooFile myBarFile
git add -u
git commit -m "git mv myFooFile myBarFile"
```

Now lets get the modification made on branch-a

```
git cherry-pick $(git show-ref branch-a)
>error: could not apply 70c80f3... rm myFooFile add myBarFile
>hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
>hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
>hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Here is the conflict:

```
git status
>On branch master
>You are currently cherry-picking commit 70c80f3.
>  (fix conflicts and run "git cherry-pick --continue")
>  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)
>
>Unmerged paths:
>  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
>
>   added by us:     myBarFile
>
>no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Unfortunately doing `git add myBarFile` then `git cherry-pick --continue` isn't the solution as it creates an empty commit.

Going with `git rm myBarFile` during resolution is not better as it creates a commit removing foo from myBarFile.

How to properly fix the cherry-pick conflict ***added by us*** and end-up in a situation where I got these 3 commits on my master branch ?

- rm myFooFile add myBarFile
- git mv myFooFile myBarFile
- First commit add myFooFile

With myBarFile containing bar ?

Note: I known that I could use `git checkout branch-a -- myBarFile` during git conflict resolution but this not the solution I'm looking for because I don't think it's the git way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor: don't do this:

```
git cherry-pick $(git show-ref branch-a)
```

Do this instead:

```
git cherry-pick branch-a
```

The cherry-pick command takes anything that identifies a revision, or even a revision range, as described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  The `git show-ref` command outputs both the hash ID *and* the name, so this tries to cherry-pick the commit twice.  (Fortunately `git cherry-pick` is smart enough to eliminate the extra.)

#### A top level view of resolving the conflict

There is no single right way to resolve the conflict.  You may use anything you like.  There are several important things to remember here:

- Cherry-picking is essentially a three-way merge a la `git merge`, except that instead of finding the actual merge base, Git just uses the parent of the commit you are cherry-picking as the merge base (and of course, the final commit is a regular non-merge commit).
- Git doesn't track file name changes.  Instead, when doing a merge operation—including a cherry-pick—Git in essence runs two `git diff` commands:

  ```
  git diff --find-renames <merge-base> HEAD     # figure out what we did
  git diff --find-renames <merge-base> <other>  # figure out what they did
  ```

  If the result is a merge conflict, Git leaves all three "interesting" files in the index—but one or two such files can be missing (as is the case here).  The `git status` command shows these as "unmerged", but you can find the full details using `git ls-files --stage`.  I'll show details in a moment.
- Your job, at this point, is simply to arrange, in the index, the files you want in the final commit to be made as a result of the merge (or cherry-pick, in this case).  These files need to be at stage zero, which is where normal, un-conflicted files live in the index.  Any entries at stage 1 represent the version of the file in the merge base, any at stage 2 represent the version of the file in the `HEAD` commit, and any at stage 3 represent the version of the file in the other commit you're merging with (or cherry-picking).

#### The conflict itself

So, let's take a look at what `git diff --find-renames` found, knowing that the merge base is the parent of the commit being cherry-picked.  We can identify the cherry-pick commit using the name `branch-a`.  Its parent is therefore `branch-a^` (again, see the gitrevisions documentation).

```
$ git diff --find-renames branch-a^ HEAD
diff --git a/myFooFile b/myBarFile
similarity index 100%
rename from myFooFile
rename to myBarFile
```

This is "what we changed": a rename operation.

```
$ git diff --find-renames branch-a^ branch-a
diff --git a/myBarFile b/myBarFile
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..5716ca5
--- /dev/null
+++ b/myBarFile
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+bar
diff --git a/myFooFile b/myFooFile
deleted file mode 100644
index 257cc56..0000000
--- a/myFooFile
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-foo
```

This is "what they changed": delete one file, add another.

Git is now charged with the job of renaming `myFooFile` to `myBarFile` (with contents `foo`) and, simultaneously, deleting `myFooFile` while creating `myBarFile` with contents `bar`.

It cannot possibly do both, so we get a conflict.  Meanwhile it *can* do the rename that we did, so it does do that in the work-tree (only), leaving `myBarFile` containing `foo`.

You want to know:

> How to properly fix the cherry-pick conflict added by us and end-up ... With myBarFile containing bar ?

All Git needs is for you to write, to the work-tree, a version of `myBarFile` containing the contents that you want, and then adjust the index so so that the entry for it is at stage zero.  Currently, what's in the index is:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 257cc5642cb1a054f08cc83f2d943e56fd3ebe99 2      myBarFile
```

and `myBarFile` has contents you *don't* want.

> Note: I known that I could use `git checkout branch-a -- myBarFile` during git conflict resolution ...

Yes: that extracts the version of `myBarFile` from the commit identified by `branch-a`, writes it into the index at stage zero, removes the entry at stage 2, and leaves everything ready for committing.  (As a bonus, it also writes the file into the work-tree so that you can see it, though Git doesn't actually care about the work-tree version at this point.)  So that's a good and fast method of achieving your desired result.  We can look at another method, though, which may be useful in some cases:

> [but] I don't think it's the git way of doing it.

Git doesn't have *a* (single) way.  Git is a tool.  Use it however you prefer.  If you prefer to adjust the work-tree contents without first touching the index, you can use `git show` to extract the `branch-a` version of the file:

```
$ git show branch-a:myBarFile > tmp
$ cat tmp
bar
$ mv tmp myBarFile
$ git add myBarFile
```

If we check the actual staging area, we find:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 5716ca5987cbf97d6bb54920bea6adde242d87e6 0       myBarFile
```

which is what we want, so we can now `git cherry-pick --continue` or `git commit` to finish off this cherry-pick:

```
$ git cherry-pick --continue
```

At this point, your preferred editor should open on a message file containing the subject `rm myFooFile add myBarFile` and additional data (since that's the commit you're cherry-picking).  Writing this out results in:

```
[master 1837c17] rm myFooFile add myBarFile                   
 Date: Fri Jun 15 22:21:48 2018 -0700
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

and `git log --oneline` shows what you want:

```
1837c17 (HEAD -> master) rm myFooFile add myBarFile
a30b874 git mv myFooFile myBarFile
bde7df5 First commit add myFooFile
```

(note: I have `log.decorate = auto` in my configuration).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detail answer but it is still unclear for me. You say: "It cannot possibly do both, so we get a conflict. Meanwhile it can do the rename that we did, so it does do that in the work-tree (only), leaving myBarFile containing foo.", after that why can't Git try to add `bar` to `myBarFile` and then create a diff with angle brackets `<<<<<<< foo ======= bar >>>>>>>` in `myBarFile`. Also why `git show :3:myBarFile` is not working during conflict resolution, I would expect to see `bar` in it at this step.

Comment: It can't do that because these are *different files*, they just happen to have the same *name*. This is the same problem, in somewhat different form, as trying to have `README.TXT` and `ReadMe.txt` on a Windows system (you can have both files on a Linux box but when you check out such a commit on Windows or MacOS Git can't do it and you get a mess). Git could in theory, but doesn't in practice, make up new names for files where the names conflict at the OS level.

Comment: OK, but why `git show :3:myBarFile` is not working during conflict resolution, I would expect to see bar in it at this step. Same reason ?

Comment: No, it's because it's in stage 2, not stage 3—stage 3 is empty at this point. See the output I got from `git ls-files --stage` above. (I do think it might be reasonable to keep the file in all *three* stages, but Git doesn't.)